# How do I upgrade from inside a VMware Image?

Tags: upgrade, vmware

I am running 10.04 within Windows 7, as a virtual machine using VMware. I want to upgrade to 10.10 now and later 11.04. Can I do this using the usual upgrade procedure ( from the update manager) ? or do I need to do something special ?

Thnx - Egon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A virtual machine doesn't really know it's virtual, so yes, it will be the same as normal.